# I get a file in use error. If I double click on the ISO file from explorer it does open

Tags: filestream

Hi folks I am new to C# using the following code I get a file in use error. If I double click on the ISO file from explorer it does open. Not sure what I am missing here if I can manually open the ISO why does my code not open it?
code:

```
  private void btnOpenISO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Clear();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "ISO files (*.iso)|*.iso|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            CDReader cd = new CDReader(fs, true, true);
            foreach (var dir in cd.Root.GetDirectories())
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(dir.Name);
                // Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```